# How to dynamically handle starting and ending threads and information in the proper way?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I haven't been able to find an applicable answer for my question, hopefully I can find someone here who can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to have the program dynamically create class instances and threads, and handle ending them, and clearing out memory before allowing more to start.

The program I'm writing involves accessing a large number of devices, sometimes periodically. I need an appropriate way to keep track of threads, which user command started them, and queuing them up so they don't overfill memory.

The user has the option to end a task which may consist of many threads, so I need to be able to blanket kill the group.

I thought an Arraylist would be best, but as seen below, I need 3 lists to work in unison, for the names, the class instances, and the threads.

```
public Class implements Runnable {

    private inner class doThings implements Runnable {

        public bool active = true

        public bool done(){
                return true;
            } 

        public run() {
            while (active){
            x=1+1
        }
        public void instakill(){
            active = false;
        }
    }

    public void mainLoop() {

        int maxThreads = 50

        List names;
        List instances;
        List threads;

        while true {

            for (each request) {

                if (threads.size < maxThreads ) {

                    names.add("unique name")
                    instances.add(new doThings())
                    threads.add(new Thread(instances.size - 1))

                    threads.get(Threads.size - 1).start

                }               
            }

            for (each instance) {

                if (doThings.done()){

                    int arrayID = instance.getIndex

                    names.remove(arrayID)
                    instances.remove(arrayID)
                    threads.remove(arrayID)

                    trim-All-Lists-To-Size();

                }

            }

        }
```

So the main loop will create new instances of the class doThings, along with a unique name, and a thread to run the class. Those are put into individual, unlinked arrays. the only way I match them up is by getting whatever index in one array and figuring since I add and subject from all arrays in uniform, it should be the same index for all. Kind of like filling up 3 separate glasses of water, and expecting them to be at the same level.

Except that's not how it plays out, of course.

If I knew how to combine the 3 bits of info (name, instance, thread) i probably wouldn't have this problem would I?

Should I just encapsulate everything into a bigger class and keep ArrayLists ( or CopyOnWriteArrayLists ) of that?

I'm not sure what is the right way to tackle this problem

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: How about using an ExecutorService or a parallelStream() to do the work?

Comment: I will take a look at Executor, I have never heard of that before. I need to be able to kill a thread when it is no longer needed, according to Oracle I should do that by declaring the thread object like: private volatile Thread threadobject; and then to kill: threadobject = null;

Comment: it was added ten+ years ago so there should be plenty of examples.

Comment: I feel like I should be reading a book or something, I learnt java in 2007/8 and haven't really touched it since then. I'm just picking it up now coding some small apps for work.

Comment: sure. I am always learning and I am a Java Champion with 18 years working in Java. Btw Executors were added in 2006. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I probably will implement the Executor, it would be more graceful than my current methods. I think I need a bit more to solve my problem though. I have added more info to the question that I was too tired to think  of at the time. My problem involves keeping track of classes, threads and names.

Comment: what are you planning to use the information for? Ie why do you need it?

Comment: I'm writing a program to connect to 50+ devices and run some commands. Everything is working except for my thread management, and the management of the batch commands. I did solve the problem (just finished implementation) using the ScheduledExecutorService and ConcurrentHashMap classes. Ended up cutting down my code by 200 lines. I posted the basic solution below if you are interested. End result is very different, it's just a working demo to try out the solution. I'm going to look into most useful/essential classes to know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Peter, you should definitively consider using the `ExecutorService` API rather than develop a similar mechanism based on thread management.

Still, regarding your original code, I think that your difficulty doesn't actually relates with thread management, but simply with data structures in Java. Instead of having three distinct lists maintained in parallel, the most common approach would simply be to encapsulate the three information in instances of some internal class (e.g. `Entry`), then have a single List of these `Entry` (that is, in modern Java: `List<Entry>`).

Another thing to know is that you should *never* remove elements in a collection while iterating on that collection, except using the iterator's remove method; if you do, you will end up with `ConcurentModificationException`. The correct way is to explicitly create an iterator on your collection (for example `list.iterator()`) then iterate over it (using `iterator.hasNext()` and `iterator.next()`), and finally remove elements using `iterator.remove().

For example, your code could look something like this:

```
public class ParentClass {

    private class RunningInstanceEntry {
        public String name;
        public Worker worker;
        public Thread thread;
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable {
        public boolean active = true;

        public boolean done() {
            return true;
        } 

        public run() {
            while (active) {
                x = 1+1;
            }
        }

        public void instakill() {
            active = false;
        }
    }

    public void mainLoop() {
        int maxThreads = 50;

        List<RunningInstanceEntry> instances =
                         new ArrayList<RunningInstanceEntry>();

        while (true) {
            for (R request : requests) {
                if (threads.size < maxThreads) {
                    RunningInstanceEntry instance =
                        new RunningInstanceEntry();

                    instance.name = "unique name";
                    instance.worker = new Worker();
                    instance.thread = new Thread(instance.worker);
                    instance.thread.start();

                    instances.add(instance);
                }               
            }

            Iterator<RunningInstanceEntry> iterator =
                    instances.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                RunningInstanceEntry instance = iterator.next();
                if (instance.worker.done()) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: there are lot of other improvements opportunities in this code, and I personally do *not* consider it has an example of good coding practice. Still, I preferred not to divert too much from the original code, since my objective here is specifically to highlight the use of structure-only classes and the `iterator.remove()` method.

Comment: Thanks heaps, that's an awesome answer. I'm working on implementing the ScheduledExecutorService and ConcurrentHashMap now. This is a really quick pseudo code model just to get the basic idea across, the actual code is a few pages, 500 lines apparently. Not sure if your suggestions would apply to the real thing, but I'm always happy to find out what I can improve on. I haven't used Java in 7+ years, briefly studying the basics in uni, so I would consider myself still quite amateur.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions!

Here is the shorthand version of what I'll be implementing:

```
public class frontpage implements Runnable {

    private class Monitor implements Runnable {
        private String x;
        public Monitor(String x) {
        this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("monitor task " + x);

            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Batch> batchlist = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
            ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                batchlist.put("monitor " + i, new Batch(
                        "monitor task " + Integer.toString(i)));
            }

            for (String key : batchlist.keySet()) {
                countdown = scheduler.schedule(batchlist.get(key), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

            while (!countdown.isDone()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            scheduler.shutdown();
            System.out.println("monitor " + x + "completed");
        }        
    }

    private class Batch implements Runnable {

        private String x;

        public Batch(String x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Task> tasklist = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
            ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                tasklist.put("task " + i, new Task(
                        "batch task " + Integer.toString(i)));
            }

            for (String key : tasklist.keySet()) {
                countdown = scheduler.schedule(tasklist.get(key), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

            while (!countdown.isDone()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }        
    }

    private class Task implements Runnable {

        private String x;

        public Task(String x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(x + " task completed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        frontpage thisone = new frontpage();
        thisone.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //run once
        Task once = new Task("once");
        once.run();
        //batch
        Batch batch = new Batch("batch");
        batch.run();
        //monitor
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor("monitor");
        monitor.run();
    }
}
```